# Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles

Tags: google-pagespeed

Whenever i am adding single js file in my site google page insight show

> "Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider
>   delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical
>   JS/styles"

,how to resolve this issue ?